# CSV data to Numpy structured array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, csv

```
Name Class Species
a     1      3
b     2      4
c     3      2
a     1      3
b     2      1
c     3      2
```

This above mentioned data will be from CSV file. need to convert this to structured array using numpy. need header from the csv become the columns labels for the array.

Need to print the mean occurrences of each names in each class (the mean of each species for class 1, class 2, and class 3)

I used `numpy.genfromtxt()`.

Comment: What do you mean by you got stuck? What is it doing? Please also post your code, so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: What's the delimiter?  How many columns?  On some lines a space between `--- 1` and others no space `---2`.  That could give any reader problems.  `genfromtxt` accepts column numbers as the `delimiter` parameter.

Comment: With proper delimiters and headers `genfromtxt` easily creates a structured from a csv file.

Comment: @hpaulj. the data is from csv file. it has columns (names, class, numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using latest numpy (1.14) on Py3.

Your sample, cleaned up:

```
In [93]: txt = """Name --- Class --- Numbers
    ...: a    ---------- 1    -------- 3
    ...: b    ---------- 2    -------- 4
    ...: c    ---------- 3    -------- 2
    ...: a    ---------- 1    -------- 3
    ...: b    ---------- 2     ------- 1
    ...: c    ---------- 3   --------- 2"""
In [94]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None, names=True, encoding=None)
In [95]: data
Out[95]: 
array([('a', '----------', 1, '--------', 3),
       ('b', '----------', 2, '--------', 4),
       ('c', '----------', 3, '--------', 2),
       ('a', '----------', 1, '--------', 3),
       ('b', '----------', 2, '-------', 1),
       ('c', '----------', 3, '---------', 2)],
      dtype=[('Name', '<U1'), ('f0', '<U10'), ('Class', '<i8'), ('f1', '<U9'), ('Numbers', '<i8')])
```

Or skipping the dashed columns:

```
In [96]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None, names=True, encoding=None, usecols=[0,2,4])
In [97]: data
Out[97]: 
array([('a', 1, 3), 
       ('b', 2, 4), 
       ('c', 3, 2), 
       ('a', 1, 3), 
       ('b', 2, 1),
       ('c', 3, 2)],
      dtype=[('Name', '<U1'), ('Class', '<i8'), ('Numbers', '<i8')])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to create a `numpy` structured array from a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.read_csv('file.csv').to_records(index=False)

# rec.array([('a', 1, 3), ('b', 2, 4), ('c', 3, 2), ('a', 1, 3), ('b', 2, 1),
#            ('c', 3, 2)], 
#           dtype=[('Name', 'O'), ('Class', '<i8'), ('Numbers', '<i8')])
```

You can then work with `numpy` or (easier) `pandas` to perform your calculations.